# The wallet connect on deposit.gnosischain.com and Safe are no longer compatible, GC uses v1, Safe v2. How do I use transaction builder to deposit?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Turns out Safe has migrated to v2 of WalletConnect, whereas Gnosis Chain continues to use v1. This means it is no longer possible to simply connect my Safe to the deposit site https://deposit.gnosischain.com/. How can I use transaction builder to deposit GNO into the deposit contract?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no backward compatibility between WC v1 and v2, and it's impossible to use WC anymore.

One workaround is to use the [Rabby wallet](https://rabby.io/) browser extension, which supports Safe wallets, and then you can use an injected wallet to connect to the Dapp [if the dapp supports it].

Regarding building the transaction with a transaction builder, it's better to contact the gnosis chain team to learn which contract and methods need to be called for a deposit.